# Is good rainfall in the UK the result of being a small island surrounded by large moving seas, having mountains and trapped salt

Tags: climate, rainfall, humidity

If the mountains were levelled and salt removed would the country experience as much rainfall?

Context
Damp in houses:
Salt absorbs moisture: think of plaster walls that grow mould from proximity to a wall with hygroscopic minerals - ie salt. Damp is a common problem in the UK where it is not in other countries even more north of the hemisphere and should be colder. There are other reasons from water ingress, indoor humidity and render bridging dpc but salt concentrates the most absorption.

Excess salt causea edema also in the body.

Salt sits at the bottom of oceans. It is easily dissolved in water.

I'm asking, if the salt were somehow removed entirely from the country would it recieve as much rain long term.

Additional context. Initially the world movement of water causing rainfall is dictated by magnetic waves of the moon on the sea, climate variations between regions, temperature and dew point and other elements but trapped moisture within small pockets of land evaporates or sinks and that gradual release of moisture in the air from salt or other water traps rise up and recirculates cumulatively potentially leading to more rain. Eg: Wales is wetter than Sussex.

Comment: Whatever salt is in the UK has got nothing to do with the amount of precipitation it receives.

Comment: @Fred what about what it keeps?

Comment: What it keeps?  I'm not sure what you mean by that, and don't believe he'd understand either.  Perhaps you should explain further??

Comment: @JeopardyTempest Fred said whatever salt is in the UK has got nothing to do with amount of precipitation it 'receives', but what about the water that is trapped in the uk from the salt, and recycling of it as it rises up again slowly.

Comment: Still unsure what you mean by trapped from the salt?  Where is it trapped at by salt?

Comment: please OP edit your question,add some sort of context and try to add some information about how the salt is related to rain in the UK.

Comment: @trondhansen context added

Comment: @SteveTomlin please take a look at the first comment the one from Fred,it answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in my comment "Whatever salt is in the UK has got nothing to do with the amount of precipitation it receives".

Now to unpick what's in your question.

**Rising Damp** - results from ground water from a high water table rising up  through the pores in brick, mortar and masonry in walls via capillary action.  Dissolved salts in the ground water moves with the water into the bricks and masonry and are deposited when the water evaporates.

**Salt sits at the bottom of oceans** - No it doesn't. There is salt in every part of the ocean. The more correct statement would be that the density of salt increases with depth of the oceans. Per unit volume of sea water, there is more salt dissolved in sea water at depth than at the surface.

**World movement of water causing rainfall is dictated by magnetic waves of the moon on the sea** - What magnetic waves on the Moon? The [magnetic field on the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field_of_the_Moon) is very weak compared to that of the Earth. Because the Earth has a rotating solid inner core, within a liquid hot outer core the Earth has a dynamo magnetic field which protects the planet from solar and cosmic radiation and enables humans and certain animals to navigate the planet via compasses or other magnetic detection devices.

What magnetism occurs on the Moon is very weak and is localized to the lunar crust. What you might be confusing is the effect the Moon's **gravity** has on Earth and its oceans. This is what causes the maritime tides on Earth.

**Salt trapping moisture on land, with moisture eventually evaporating from the salt leading to humid air above the land which results in rain** - This is not peculiar to salt; soil does the same thing. [Forests transpire](https://www.thoughtco.com/forest-transpiration-water-cycle-4117845) leading to localized rainfall - recirculating the water within a region.

Salt deposits on land do not draw in rain clouds. Neither do they force or entice the clouds to dump rain on any such deposits.

You were closer to the truth in the title to your question. The reason why the UK receives as much rain as it does is because it is a small island in a very active ocean. The [furthest point from the coast](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/england/derbyshire/3090539.stm) is "Church Flatts Farm in Derbyshire, which is which is 70 miles (113 km) from the nearest coast, the mean low water line at Fosdyke Wash, on the edge of The Wash, south of Boston, in Lincolnshire".

Because of this, the air in the UK is humid and it just takes a cold front to cause the atmospheric moisture to precipitate.

As for Wales being wetter than Sussex, Wales has mountains that act a barriers to clouds moving from the west. As the clouds rise to go over the mountains they drop their moisture as rain. To the east of the mountains there will most likely be a rain shadow region which receives much less rainfall. Sussex is further to the east and has no coastal or western mountains. Any rain cloud can more easily blow over Sussex and thus Sussex receives less rain.